# How can I fix the Kivy Textfield not accepting user input while developing rule-based expert systems with Expetra?

Tags: kivy, kivymd, textinput, python-3.9, experta

I were developing rule based expert systems with experta and the user interface with kivy. The kivy textfield is not accepting the user input, and it can't process, transform and give recommendation for the user, please help me in fixing it

The .kv file is like this, i gave id for all of them

```
ScreenManager:
    Main:
    ShortWindow:
<Main>:
    name : 'main'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Crop Recommendation'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Temperature'
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.75}
    MDTextField:
        id: input_1
        on_text_validate:root.textinput(self)
    MDLabel:
        text: 'weather'
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.68}
    MDTextField:
        id: input_2
        on_text_validate:root.textinput(self)
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: startbtn
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
        text: 'Get Recommendation'
        on_press:
            root.recommendation()
            app.show_recommendation()
```

and the .py file is like this and i have tried to call textinput ids and the functions accordingly

```
class Main(Screen):
    input_1 = StringProperty("input_1")
    input_2 = StringProperty("input_2")
    def textInput(self, widget):
        self.input_1 = widget.text
        self.input_2 = widget.text

    def recommendation(self):
        object1 = Set_data(

            self.textInput(self.ids.input_1),
            self.textInput(self.ids.input_2),
        )
        object1.data_transform()
        preprocess()
    engine = Greetings()
    engine.reset()
    engine.declare(Fact(temp=t))
    engine.declare(Fact(weather=w))

    engine.run()
    print(engine.facts)
```